# Calculating Point Density using Python

Tags: python

I have a list of X and Y coordinates from geodata of a specific part of the world. I want to assign each coordinate, a weight, based upon where it lies in the graph.

For Example: If a point lies in a place where there are a lot of other nodes around it, it lies in a high density area, and therefore has a higher weight.

The most immediate method I can think of is drawing circles of unit radius around each point and then calculating if the other points lie within in and then using a function, assign a weight to that point. But this seems primitive.

I've looked at pySAL and NetworkX but it looks like they work with graphs. I don't have any edges in the graph, just nodes.

Comment: I'd say this should go on math.SE, instead. The primary problem is what procedure to use, not how to implement it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A standard solution would be using KDE ([Kernel Density Estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation)).
Search on web: "KDE Estimation" you will find enormous links.
in Google type: KDE Estimation ext:pdf
Also, Scipy has KDE, follow this http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html. There is working example codes there ;)

Answer (score 5):

If you have a lot of points, you may compute nearest neighbors more efficiently using a [KDTree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.spatial as spatial
points = np.array([(1, 2), (3, 4), (4, 5), (100,100)])
tree = spatial.KDTree(np.array(points))
radius = 3.0

neighbors = tree.query_ball_tree(tree, radius)
print(neighbors)
# [[0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [1, 2], [3]]
```

[tree.query_ball_tree](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) returns indices (of `points`) of the nearest neighbors. For example, `[0,1]` (at index 0) means `points[0]` and `points[1]` are within `radius` distance from `points[0]`. `[0,1,2]` (at index 1) means `points[0]`, `points[1]` and `points[2]` are within `radius` distance from `points[1]`.

```
frequency = np.array(map(len, neighbors))
print(frequency)
# [2 3 2 1]
density = frequency/radius**2
print(density)
# [ 0.22222222  0.33333333  0.22222222  0.11111111]
```

Comment: `frequency` calculation didn't worked for in python 3.8.12. I calculated frequency this way: `frequency = np.array([len(i) for i in neighbors])`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do have edges, and they are the distances between the nodes. In your case, you have a complete graph with weighted edges.

Simply derive the distance from each node to each other node -- which gives you `O(N^2)` in time complexity --, and use both nodes and edges as input to one of these approaches you found.

Happens though your problem seems rather an analysis problem other than anything else; you should try to run some clustering algorithm on your data, like `K-means`, that clusters nodes based on a distance function, in which you can simply use the euclidean distance.

The result of this algorithm is exactly what you'll need, as you'll have clusters of close elements, you'll know what and how many elements are assigned to each group, and you'll be able to, according to these values, generate the *coefficient* you want to assign to each node.

The only concern worth pointing out here is that you'll have to determine how many `clusters` -- `k-means, k-clusters` -- you want to create.

Answer (score 1):

You initial inclination to draw a circle around each point and count the number of other points in that circle is a good one and as mentioned by unutbu, a KDTree will be a fast way to solve this problem.

This can be done very easily with PySAL, which using scipy's kdtree under the hood.

```
import pysal
import numpy
pts = numpy.random.random((100,2)) #generate some random points
radius = 0.2 #pick an arbitrary radius

#Build a Spatial Weights Matrix
W = pysal.threshold_continuousW_from_array(pts, threshold=radius)
# Note: if your points are in Latitude and Longitude you can increase the accuracy by
#       passing the radius of earth to this function and it will use arc distances.
# W = pysal.threshold_continuousW_from_array(pts, threshold=radius, radius=pysal.cg.RADIUS_EARTH_KM)

print W.cardinalities
#{0: 10, 1: 15, ..... }
```

If your data is in a Shapefile, simply replace threshold_continuousW_from_array with threshold_continuousW_from_shapefile, see the docs for details.