# How can I combine a scatter plot with a density heatmap?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-express

I have a series of scatterplots (one example below), but I want to modify it so that the colors of the points in the plot become more red (or "hot") when they are clustered more closely with other points, while points that are spread out further are colored more blue (or "cold"). Is it possible to do this?

[image: scatterplot example]

Currently, my code is pretty basic in its set up.

```
import plotly.express as px
    
fig = px.scatter(data, x='A', y='B', trendline='ols')
```

Comment: You can use the color parameter on `px.scatter()` to color the points by the values in the dataframe column.  There is an example here: https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/.  If you post your code the community will better be able to help you.

Comment: This question may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070565/calculating-point-density-using-python  You can calculate the kernel density of the points and add a column to your dataframe and then use this column to style using plotly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`scipy.stats.gaussian_kde`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html) you can calculate the density and then use this to color the plot:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from scipy import stats

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x':[0,0,1,1,2,2,2.25,2.5,2.5,3,3,4,2,4,8,2,2.75,3.5,2.5], 
    'y':[0,2,3,2,1,2,2.75,2.5,3,3,4,1,5,4,8,4,2.75,1.5,3.25]
})
kernel = stats.gaussian_kde([df.x, df.y])
df['z'] = kernel([df.x, df.y])
fig = px.scatter(df, x='x', y='y', color='z', trendline='ols', color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Bluered)
```

output:
[image: scatterplot]

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! But can I ask, what does the line `stats.gaussian_kde(values)(positions)` do (I am consolidating a little bit)? I understand that `stats.gaussian_kde(values)` makes a gaussian_kde object, but then what is happening when we are passing in the `positions` array?

Comment: Great question. I was mostly following along with the [example here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html).  I edited the answer to simplify it a bit removing some of the numpy code that was just shaping the data.  My interpretation of this is that `kernel = stats.gaussian_kde([df.x, df.y])` forms the density cloud object and then `df['z'] = kernel([df.x, df.y])` takes samples of this cloud at your points.

Comment: I think `values = [df.x, df.y]` and `df['z'] = stats.gaussian_kde(values)(values)` would work as well.